# "...I don't have money, but what I do have *are* a very particular set of skills." Is this correct?

Tags: grammar, verbs, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, copular-verbs

> If you are looking for ransom I can tell you I don't have money, but what I do have *are* a very particular set of skills.

I'm talking about that verb in italics, because I'm not sure if I'm an idiot or my 'friend' is. Because I think it's supposed to be *is* instead of *are*.

Comment: a set - singular

Comment: No doubt a duplicate - questions about singular/plural with a set/group/etc. BrE vs AmE etc.

Comment: Related, I think: [verb agreement: what he is looking for are/is books](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323837)

Answer (score 1):

The object you have is singular (a *set*), so... my sentence just answered your question. What you have *is* a set of skills.

Comment: As this is an answer, a little more elaboration with a citation would be helpful.

Comment: Here you go?
www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp

Comment: edit that into your answer if you will.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't subscribe to the [*“what” or “all” clause takes a singular verb*](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/06/subject-complement.html) rule, the question here is whether the verb should agree plurally with the [accusative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_case) noun *set* or the [genitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case) noun *skills*. I couldn't find any information on this but I would say that either is acceptable. If I was feeling particularly pedantic I might prefer the former.